# How to make a proxy server proxying through a third party proxy?

Tags: node.js, proxy

I want to write a proxy server on nodeJS that will take a free http-proxy from the pool and proxy the request through this proxy.

But my proxy doesn't work because its SSL-name doesn't match the site's SSL name. When using http, sites with HTTPS do not work. Tell me, please, what to do?

```
const https = require('node:https');
const fs = require('node:fs');
const { HttpsProxyAgent } = require('https-proxy-agent');

const MAX_TRAFFIC = 100 * 1024 * 1024;

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./cert/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert/agent2-cert.pem'),
};

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
  const proxyAgent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxyUrl)

  const targetConfig = {
    host: req.headers.host,
    port: 443,
    path: req.url,
    method: req.method,
    headers: req.headers,
    agent: proxyAgent
  };

  let traffic = 0;
    
  const targetReq = https.request(targetConfig, (targetRes) => {
    res.writeHead(targetRes.statusCode, targetRes.headers);

    targetRes.on('data', (chunk) => {
      traffic += chunk.length;
      
      if (traffic > MAX_TRAFFIC) {
        console.log(`Traffic limit exceeded: ${traffic} bytes`);
        targetReq.destroy();
        res.end('Limited');
      }

      console.log(traffic);
    });

    targetRes.on('end', () => {
      console.log(`Traffic: ${traffic} bytes`);
    });

    targetRes.pipe(res);
  });

  req.pipe(targetReq);

}).listen(8000, '0.0.0.0');
```